# How can I create a foreach with a key that has a space in the name?

Tags: arrays, json, knockout.js, foreach

I'm trying to create a ko foreach to pull data from an observable array created from an external JSON file. For some reason, the developer of the program that supplies the JSON file decided to use spaces in a few of the string names, such as "Network Devices". Knockout seems to have trouble with whitespaces, even when I add \s or put it in quotes. It also seems like there's no way to create a foreach by the key's index value. How can I go about adding the whitespace to the foreach, or renaming the problematic values inside the array?

Right now my foreach code starts with `<!-- ko foreach: Network Devices -->`, and I've also tried `$index[12]` and several other identifiers with no luck.

Comment: Can you please add some code you've tried? Make sure format properly with the editor so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just use some vanilla javascript:

```
var json = {
    "Network Devices": "yes",
    "Computer": ["keyboard", "mouse", "processor"],
    "Types of fruits": ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]
};
for ( var key in json ) {
    var obj = json[key];
    console.log(key,obj);
}
```

Now you can access `obj` to manipulate just that part of the object.

[image: loop through javascript object]

If you must, you can go through and encode all of the keys so they don't contain spaces. This will change `"Network Devices"` to `"Network%20Devices"`

```
var json = {
    "Network Devices": "yes",
    "Computer": ["keyboard", "mouse", "processor"],
    "Types of fruits": ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]
};
var new_object = {};
for ( var key in json ) {
    new_object[encodeURIComponent(key)] = json[key];
}
console.log(new_object);
```

When it comes time to decode the key, use `decodeURIComponent(key)`

Or you could just replace the spaces with underscores: `"Network_Devices"`

```
var new_object = {};
for ( var key in json ) {
    new_object[key.replace(' ','_')] = json[key];
}
console.log(new_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bracket notation in your data-bind. Use `$data` to refer to the current binding context:

```js
var myData = {
  "Weird Key": [1,2,3]
};

ko.applyBindings(myData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: $data['Weird Key'] -->

  <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>

<!-- /ko -->
```